# Filter through array to find a match then execute else statement if no matches

Tags: reactjs

Currently, the function executes the `else` statement as soon as there is no match.

I want the function to loop over all of the followers in the array first, and then, if no match exists, execute the else statement.

I have an array of `followers`. I want to filter through all of the followers in the array and find a match with my `user` value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (followers != []) {
      followers.filter((follower) => {
        if (follower.username === user) {
          setIsFollower(true);
          setUnlock(true);
          // setShowLockPage(true);
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: "SHOW_LOCK_PAGE",
            item: {
              showLockPage: true,
            },
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }, [followers]);
```

Comment: have a look at Array's `some` and `every` functions, which have been part of JS for a very long time, but surprisingly few folks know about.

Comment: Another function if you need the object you are looking for is `find`. You could use `some` or `find` to figure out if the follower is present in your collection then do a basic if / else statement for your logic. `const follower = followers.find(f => f.username === user); if (follower) { /* if found */ } else { /* if not found */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (followers.length > 0 ) {
      const isUserExist = followers.some((follower => follower.username === user))
      if (!isUserExist){
          return dispatch({
            type: "SHOW_LOCK_PAGE",
            item: {
              showLockPage: true,
            },
          });
      }
      // executes only if (isUserExist === true)
      setIsFollower(true);
      setUnlock(true);
    }
  }, [followers]);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!